# Blob detection as Constraint satisfaction problem?

Tags: np-complete, image-processing, computer-vision, graphics, constraint-programming

In image processing I have a black and white image which is represented by matrix {0,1}, I have to find blob (a region of connected pixels) in it. I'm confused, can this problem be reduced to Constraint Satisfaction problem (as p/np complete)?

[image: Typical Example with white blobs]

Black and white image with white blobs.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? (You may profit from reading our [reference material on complexity theory](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/845#845).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constraint satisfaction problem (CSP) is **NP**-complete.  Identifying blobs is a question about graph connectivity which is in **P**.  Therefore, yes, the question you're asking reduces *to* CSP but this doesn't tell you anything useful: it just says that CSP is at least as hard as this problem but it might be harder.  (In fact, it is strictly harder if **P**$\neq$**NP**.)  Since your problem is in **P**, it is not (believed to be) **NP**-complete.

A related question is whether the problem can be expressed directly as a CSP without needing a reduction.

If a blob is any connected region then, in particular, any blob contains two adjacent pixels and any two adjacent pixels are part of a blob.  Therefore, if all you want to know is whether an image contains at least one blob, this is a constraint satisfaction problem.

However, if you want to identify a whole blob (e.g., output a list of all the pixels within some blob) or identify or count all the blobs, the problem is no longer a CSP.  The reason for this is that CSPs are not able to express connectivity conditions: there is no CSP in a finite constraint language that says "This graph is connected" because every instance of CSP is equivalent to a first-order formula and first-order logic can't tell the difference between connected and disconnected graphs.

Comment: @Andy Unless **P=NP**, it is not **NP**-complete. Also, please check the definition of **NP**-completeness and reductions. All the problems you are trying to solve are in **P** so, by definition, are in **NP** so, by definition, are reducible *to* any **NP**-complete problem.

Comment: The problem is I m not able to reduce my above problem to NP-complete problem. Please help.

Comment: @Andy I don't understand why you want to reduce it to an **NP**-complete problem but, if you insist, you're allowed a polynomial time reduction and the problem can be solved in polynomial time. So just solve the problem in the reduction and output a trivial instance.